# How to remove values in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just a little question : 
Now i have this structure

```
images
---- uniqueId
-------- id_logement : 1747657
-------- image : dataimage
---- uniqueId
-------- id_logement : 1747657
-------- image : dataimage
---- uniqueId
-------- id_logement : 985445234
-------- image : dataimage
```

And it's better ! Thank you !! but :
How can i remove all the images where id_logement = 1747657 ?
i tried that

```
        firebase.database().ref('logements/'+key).remove();
        firebase.database().ref('geofire/'+key).remove();
        firebase.database().ref('images').child('id_logement').equalTo(key).remove();
```

with key = 1747657 but without success for the images ! This UniqueId makes me nervous ! Please can you send me more advices ? thank you very much

Comment: Hey Pablo, just added an answer. Sorry on the delay. Regards. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you want to bulk delete data based on a query, you will need to retrieve it first and delete it setting its values to null and committing the changes with `update`.

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('images');
ref.orderByChild('id_logement').equalTo(key).once('value', snapshot => {
     const updates = {};
     snapshot.forEach(child => updates[child.key] = null);
     ref.update(updates);
});
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/23/).

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for ! Now i can remove (set to null) for each in one time ! Thank you very much !

Comment: what if we want to delete a specific data node ?

Comment: @BhargavSushant ref('node').remove()?

Answer (score 5):

There is actually an easier way.

Just call the [`ref`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#ref) property in your snapshot, and use `.on('child_added',...)`

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('images');
ref.orderByChild('id_logement').equalTo(key).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
     snapshot.ref.remove()
});
```

Comment: Good catch. Even though this makes the code looks tiny I would say this is not the best choice in terms of performance and could result in not expected behaviors. This code will call `remove` for each one of the child nodes being removed while with the solution I have provided we call `update` only once. Also, since this is an observer you will be listening for any other adding child and will be removing the nodes that have been just added.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:-

```
 rootRef.child("images").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot :  snapshot.getChildren())
            {
               if(dataSnapshot.child("id_logement").getValue().toString().equals("1747657"))
               {
                   dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
               }
            }           
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good answer. But OP was looking for a JavaScript solution, something that was easy to overlook due to the lack of platform tags.