# Firebase: remove child element is not working

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database

I have already tried different kind of solutions to remove child element by key from Firebase-Database, but without any effect. What I am doing wrong?

My database structure looks like this, where `players` is under the root of the database
[image]

I have an Angular 2 Single Page Application, where in the **index.html** included FireBase-client initialization:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.3/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {/*....*/};
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

Regardless [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data) both deletions are not working:

```
removePlayer1(id: any): Promise<Response> {
    return firebase.database().ref("players").child(id).once('value')
           .then((snap: any) => {
              console.log("Player was removed", id, snap);
              snap.remove();
           }).catch((err: any) => this.handleError(err));
}

removePlayer2(id: any): Promise<Response> {
    return firebase.database().ref().child('players')
          .child(id).remove().then((r: any) => {
              console.log("Player was removed", id);
          }).catch((err: any) => this.handleError(err));
}
```

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684411/3146132) still is not working:

```js
removePlayer(id: any): Promise<Response> {
    var updates = {};
    updates[id] = null;
    return firebase.database().ref("players").update(updates)
             .then((r: any) => {
               console.log("Player was removed", id, r);
             }).catch((err: any) => this.handleError(err));
}
```

At the same time update and insert child values perfectly works:

```js
savePlayer(player: IPlayer): Promise<Response> {
    let playerRef: any;
    if (!player._id) {
        playerRef = firebase.database().ref().child('players').push().set(player);
    } else {
        var updates = {};
        updates[player._id] = player;
        playerRef = firebase.database().ref().child('players').update(updates);
    }

    return playerRef.catch((err: any) => this.handleError(err));
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why [the mentioned link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684411/3146132) from StakOverflow didn't help me, but I was near and as a result my solution looks like this:

```
removePlayer(id: any): Promise<any> {
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child('players');
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        ref.child(id).once("value", function (snapshot: any) {
            var updates = {};
            updates[snapshot.key] = null;
            ref.update(updates).then((r: any) => {
                resolve(r);
            }).catch((e: any) => reject(e));
        }).catch((e: any) => reject(e));
    });
}
```